# NoSuchElementException on while loop

Tags: java, exception

So, I'm working on a class that is supposed to read in data from a .csv file. There are three arrays that store information from each line of the file. The character at the beginning of each line will determine what array to store the information from the file in later on. So, it has to be sized through a while loop iterating through the file and a Scanner. However, a 'NoSuchElementException' is thrown and I've narrowed it down to the while loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
     while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
         scan.nextLine();

         if(scan.next().equals("A")){
            aLength++;
         }
         else if(scan.next().equals("B")){
            bLength++;
         }
         else if(scan.next().equals("C")){
            cLength++;
         }

     } 

     // aProject = new int[aLength];
     // bProject = new int[bLength];
     // cProject = new int[cLength];
```

Answer (score 5):

You're calling .next() three times. What you really want to do is call it once, save the result in a variable, then test whether that variable equals `"A"`, `"B"`, or `"C"`.

Comment: Alright, I did that and the exception went away, however it seems that the arrays still aren't sized properly. [link](http://i53.tinypic.com/5a3zlv.png)

Comment: Most likely, you need to do extra parsing on the line. The code you have above tests the entire line. You could always use `line.startsWith("A")`, etc.